# Pass Azure connection to console app in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a custom console application that needs access to some Azure services (KeyVault, VM management, etc.).
I need to call this console app within a task in an Azure DevOps pipeline.
How can I pass an Azure service connection and use it from the application?
I thought that some information should be accessible in an Azure PowerShell task, but I can't find enough reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create a service principle and access the your azure subscription with this service principle.

Please refer document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) to create a service and assign it to a role with the right permission to access your subscription.
If you would like to create service principle with azure cli, please refer steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal)

To use the service principle in your console app. You can refer to [this example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/09/27/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis/).

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) for more information about Azure Rest api. For Azure .net sdk please refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net)

Comment: Thank you very much.
Ideally I would have liked to reuse the connection available within the context of the Azure PowerShell task, but this would solve my issue requiring some additional work.

Comment: Hey, I'm in a similar situation here, I tried following your links but I get redirected to a list of books and courses, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is a link to web.archive for the sample

https://web.archive.org/web/20190108114957/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/09/27/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis/

Comment: And here is an updated link to the sample that works

https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2018/04/24/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis/

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would depend on whether the specific build/release task that you're using supports passing Service Connection as an argument. Looking at the [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) task reference, I can see that `azureSubscription` parameter is accepted as an input to the task, which should let you configure your subscription.

[image: Azure Powershell task configuration]

Hope this addresses your query!

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not configuring the subscription for the task.. the problem is that I would like to access the subscription from a console application that runs in the context of that PowerShell task